# Using ServiceStack REST to receive data without a POCO on the server

Tags: servicestack, nlog

We're trying to write a ServiceStack Rest method to received data from the NLOG WebService Target.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target

It appears that Nlog will send a WCF formatted Json POST based on the class NlogEvents

http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/nlog/nlog/src/NLog/LogReceiverService/NLogEvents.cs

We can resolve this object as an argument to a post method. But how do we specify the ROUTE as we cant decorate it with an ROUTE attribute?

Also, it appears that this object already has a several attributes that were added from the WCF support.  Is there another way to specify the Poco recieve object?

Also, The Nlog webservice has flags to format the data as Rfc3986 or Rfc2396 but im nor sure if that does anything for us.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ServiceStack's [routing docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing), you can register routes on DTOs you don't own using the [Fluent API](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#fluent-api), or [dynamically attach attributes to Types](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#dynamically-adding-route-attributes).

You don't need to use NLog's exact Types in Services, i.e. you can just use a copy of the DTOs for your Service contract and annotate them freely. If needed you can use [Auto Mapping](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) to easily copy data from DTOs to NLog Types.